# Extracting JS variable information inside script tag

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm retrieving an HTML page from a URL and want to extract information from a `script` tag within that HTML. I am specifically looking for this particular `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var zomato = zomato || {};
    zomato.menuPages = [{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg","filename":"4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"FOOD","title":"FOOD","menu_type_class":"FOOD","real_menu_type":"FOOD","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344370},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg","filename":"0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"FOOD","title":"FOOD","menu_type_class":"FOOD","real_menu_type":"FOOD","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344371},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg","filename":"6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"FOOD","title":"FOOD","menu_type_class":"FOOD","real_menu_type":"FOOD","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344365},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg","filename":"ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"FOOD","title":"FOOD","menu_type_class":"FOOD","real_menu_type":"FOOD","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344366},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg","filename":"3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"FOOD","title":"FOOD","menu_type_class":"FOOD","real_menu_type":"FOOD","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344367},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg","filename":"733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"FOOD","title":"FOOD","menu_type_class":"FOOD","real_menu_type":"FOOD","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344368},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg","filename":"69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"FOOD","title":"FOOD","menu_type_class":"FOOD","real_menu_type":"FOOD","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344369},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg","filename":"9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344483},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg","filename":"b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344484},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg","filename":"439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344485},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg","filename":"854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344486},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg","filename":"7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344487},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg","filename":"f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344488},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/c734ed73e8e5f15f2e3ef9e287bf86f7.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/c734ed73e8e5f15f2e3ef9e287bf86f7.jpg","filename":"c734ed73e8e5f15f2e3ef9e287bf86f7.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/c734ed73e8e5f15f2e3ef9e287bf86f7.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/c734ed73e8e5f15f2e3ef9e287bf86f7.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344489},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/0cbe5c590f3d5312238de6b00cc9b0a9.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/0cbe5c590f3d5312238de6b00cc9b0a9.jpg","filename":"0cbe5c590f3d5312238de6b00cc9b0a9.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/0cbe5c590f3d5312238de6b00cc9b0a9.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/0cbe5c590f3d5312238de6b00cc9b0a9.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344490},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/3db4f82866e075bb1852990a0cdbe30a.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/3db4f82866e075bb1852990a0cdbe30a.jpg","filename":"3db4f82866e075bb1852990a0cdbe30a.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/3db4f82866e075bb1852990a0cdbe30a.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/3db4f82866e075bb1852990a0cdbe30a.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344477},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/1e0df9160c02273466e96239eae1a555.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/1e0df9160c02273466e96239eae1a555.jpg","filename":"1e0df9160c02273466e96239eae1a555.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/1e0df9160c02273466e96239eae1a555.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/1e0df9160c02273466e96239eae1a555.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344478},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/0d7fd654ec9f090883fa428df0f1ebb2.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/0d7fd654ec9f090883fa428df0f1ebb2.jpg","filename":"0d7fd654ec9f090883fa428df0f1ebb2.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/0d7fd654ec9f090883fa428df0f1ebb2.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/0d7fd654ec9f090883fa428df0f1ebb2.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344479},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/da16fc1d8d9641581fca258cbcb99f80.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/da16fc1d8d9641581fca258cbcb99f80.jpg","filename":"da16fc1d8d9641581fca258cbcb99f80.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/da16fc1d8d9641581fca258cbcb99f80.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/da16fc1d8d9641581fca258cbcb99f80.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344480},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/5336b40a11d4486db5e3a4bcfb0e9ae8.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/5336b40a11d4486db5e3a4bcfb0e9ae8.jpg","filename":"5336b40a11d4486db5e3a4bcfb0e9ae8.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/5336b40a11d4486db5e3a4bcfb0e9ae8.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/5336b40a11d4486db5e3a4bcfb0e9ae8.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344481},{"url":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/c96e340be834ecf086536234a56e7626.jpg","href":"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/menus\/705\/51705\/c96e340be834ecf086536234a56e7626.jpg","filename":"c96e340be834ecf086536234a56e7626.jpg","url_master":"menus_original\/705\/51705\/c96e340be834ecf086536234a56e7626.jpg","path_master":"\/home\/foodie\/zomato_data\/menus_original\/705\/51705\/c96e340be834ecf086536234a56e7626.jpg","data_center":"sng","menu_type":"BAR","title":"BAR","menu_type_class":"BAR","real_menu_type":"BAR","is_salt_special_menu":0,"start_date":"","consumer_upload":0,"start_date_formatted":"","end_date":"","end_date_formatted":"","id":129344482}];
    zomato.menuTypes = ["DEFAULT","FOOD","BAR","DELIVERY","SPECIAL","TAKEAWAY","INTERNAL"];
    zomato.currentMenuPage = 1;
</script>
```

That list goes on for quite a while. I am using [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). This:

```
soup.find_all('script')[14]
```

gives me the exact `script` tag I want. However, once I have done that, I am not sure how to parse further.

Is there a way I can access `zomato.menuPages` as a python list and then access its elements? If there are no decent Python solutions, maybe something in JS?

Comment: Your question must be self-contained, it cannot rely on off-site content. You'd quoted the necessary information in the question (except you might want to show the end of the array you're interested in), so in the process of generally cleaning up the question (punctuation is followed by spaces, thoughts should be separated into separate sentences, etc.) I removed the unnecessary external link.

Comment: why the downvote and the edit ?

Comment: The reason I put up the URL was the array was a big one and it would have been convenient for someone to test it out in realtime.

Comment: Just include a complete-enough subset of the array ***in*** the question. I'd probably also include a little bit following the array for context. But linking to random off-site pages is not how things are done here, not least because the page can change over time, making the link useless to people trying to learn from the question and its answers in the future.

Comment: Good luck with it, btw. If you're okay with the result breaking when the page changes (comments added in the middle or something, perhaps intentionally to break scraping), you can probably do string matching, possibly with regex, but regex solutions to proper language parsing tend to fail. If you need to be more robust than that, you'll need a JavaScript parser.

Comment: thanks..i understand your concerns with off-site pages going dead over a period of time..I have updated the question with the entire script tag..Speaking of Javascript parsers,do you know of anyone suitable for this task ?

Comment: Afraid not, Python isn't my thing. I'm sure there's one out there, though.

Comment: @Amistad if you can conveniently get away for parsing via regex -then go with that... Otherwise - if the page is designed to deliberately be awkward to scrape then you might want to investigate automating a browser and getting that to retrieve attributes from variables in the executed javascript... (have a look for python javascript headless browsing and selenium - quite a few bits out there to accomplish the task)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found [jsxml](https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml) pretty effective, it parses *javascript* properties/functions into xml trees:

```
import js2xml
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(the_html,"html.parser")

tree = js2xml.parse(soup.find("script", text=re.compile("zomato.menuPages\s+=")).text)
print(js2xml.pretty_print(tree))
```

In the middle of the tree you will see:

```
  <assign operator="=">
    <left>
      <dotaccessor>
        <object>
          <identifier name="zomato"/>
        </object>
        <property>
          <identifier name="menuTypes"/>
        </property>
      </dotaccessor>
    </left>
    <right>
      <array>
        <string>DEFAULT</string>
        <string>FOOD</string>
        <string>BAR</string>
        <string>DELIVERY</string>
        <string>SPECIAL</string>
        <string>TAKEAWAY</string>
        <string>INTERNAL</string>
      </array>
    </right>
```

There you have the assign node, with the `operator="="` inside the *left* node, then you have the `dotaccessor` node which contains the `object` and `property` childs nodes, so basically we just need to find the correct left assign using the *object/property* inside the *dotproperty* node and get the following array, a quick example of using the tree to get the array and the content:

```
In [5]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [6]: soup = BeautifulSoup(s,"html.parser")

In [7]: tree = js2xml.parse(soup.script.text)

In [8]: array = tree.xpath("//left[./dotaccessor/property/identifier[@name='menuPages']]/following::array[1]")[0]

In [9]: for node in array.xpath(".//object/*"):
   ...:         print(node.xpath("@name"), node.xpath(".//text()") or node.xpath(".//@value") )
   ...:     
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/4bab50546bf3314e25dea4310ddf524e.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['title'], ['FOOD'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['FOOD'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344370'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/0a284792e41edbb5ba5bbc7b0cde26db.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['title'], ['FOOD'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['FOOD'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344371'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/6ff338c3891bca1cc61574e9864b15ae.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['title'], ['FOOD'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['FOOD'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344365'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/ff5a5ea0945782ad1d82102461a39b52.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['title'], ['FOOD'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['FOOD'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344366'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/3cb04e221c4db345ceb41b638d9faa6a.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['title'], ['FOOD'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['FOOD'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344367'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/733759862d474dfd8e710fa08e78849b.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['title'], ['FOOD'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['FOOD'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344368'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/69144be9b82cbba9adcc9de35003522d.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['title'], ['FOOD'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['FOOD'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['FOOD'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344369'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/9dfd7dcc0e45639acbde792781012e0d.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['title'], ['BAR'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['BAR'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344483'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/b89c707ff99087cd8098ddaf3b5f1346.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['title'], ['BAR'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['BAR'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344484'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/439bf88da8bfce35ba44c6f206360a90.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['title'], ['BAR'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['BAR'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344485'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/854abd602c815f84dcaa2fdea1c22f81.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['title'], ['BAR'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['BAR'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344486'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/7670f299fd8f065252b94665df390790.jpg'])
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['title'], ['BAR'])
(['menu_type_class'], ['BAR'])
(['real_menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['is_salt_special_menu'], ['0'])
(['start_date'], [''])
(['consumer_upload'], ['0'])
(['start_date_formatted'], [''])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344487'])
(['url'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg'])
(['href'], ['https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/menus/705/51705/f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg'])
(['filename'], ['f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg'])
(['url_master'], ['menus_original/705/51705/f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg'])
(['path_master'], ['/home/foodie/zomato_data/menus_original/705/51705/f308c376afe08aed9b4ccf38eb0d6652.jpg'])
.........................................................
(['data_center'], ['sng'])
(['menu_type'], ['BAR'])
(['end_date'], [''])
(['end_date_formatted'], [''])
(['id'], ['129344482'])
```

The output is truncated as there is way too much, you can find specific *properties/values* with your *xpaths* as you would with any tree.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a way to do that is to make use of **regular expressions** which of course is not the most easy thing to do but comes in handy sometimes. So what I tried is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests  
import re 

# I didn't post the url for typical reasons 
url = "the_url"

r = requests.get(url)
response = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
x = soup.findAll(name = 'script')[14] 


# use regular expression
values = re.findall(r'zomato..*?=\s*(.*?);', str(x), re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

So what this regular expression will do in this case is to give you 
a list consisted of 4 elements - for example the 2nd element will be 
`zomato.menuPages` as you asked for.
Then you can process `zomato.menuPages` a bit more, like:

```
k = ''.join(values[1])
w = k[1:-1]
list = w.split("{",21)
print list[1]
```

Then you could try to convert the items of the `list` from string -> dictionary to be able to parse them more easily(using json or ast maybe).

Also you could parse each of these values(I refer to the values list) using another regular expression.
Also using the `groupdict` function from the regex module you could create a dictionary from each element of the list based on certain regex rules.
Well, I hope it will be of some help!